# How to remove error icon and error text when Textinputlayout is on focus

Tags: java, android

I want to hide or remove end error icon and replace it by an end icon password toggle when typing on Textinputedittext.
I used setOnfocusChangeListener and addTextChangeListener but it not work
this is my xml and java code

`

```
     mBinding.textFieldPassword.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            mBinding.textFieldPassword.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_NONE);

        } else {


            mBinding.edtPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextChangeListener() {

               @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


                    if (mBinding.textFieldPassword.isErrorEnabled()){
                        mBinding.textFieldPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    }

                    if (Objects.requireNonNull(mBinding.edtPassword.getText()).toString().length() > 0) {

                        mBinding.textFieldPassword.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_PASSWORD_TOGGLE);
                    } else {
                        mBinding.textFieldPassword.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_NONE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

`

this below is xml

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_field_password"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:hint="@string/txt_password"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="10dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="10dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
    app:boxStrokeErrorColor="@color/red"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
    app:errorTextColor="@color/red">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"

        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[after the error is showed, when I type on edittext, error icon is
still display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdIUZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `TextWatcher` removing the error message.

Something like:

```
    textField.editText?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            validateEditText(textField,s)
        }
    })

    textField.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        if (!hasFocus) {
            validateEditText(v as TextInputLayout,(v as EditText).text)
        }
    }
```

with:

```
private fun validateEditText(textField: TextInputLayout,s: Editable) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
        textField.error = null
    } else {
        textField.error = "Error"
    }
}
```